# How do I improve the perfomance of my delete-query if the bottleneck appears to be I/O?

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete, query-performance

I have a (badly designed) database table (postgres) that I'm trying to clean up. The table is about  270 GB in size, 38K rows (+- 70 MB per row --> columns contain file contents).

In parallel with changing the design to no longer contain files, I want to remove 80% of the data to reduce disk usage. Hence, I've tried to following query:

```
DELETE FROM table_name.dynamic_data 
WHERE table_name.env = 'AE'
```

Which should cover +- 25% of the data. This query times out without any warning, or sometimes reporting that the logs file are full: *PANIC:  could not write to file "pg_xlog/xlogtemp.32455": No space left on device*

I've tried to

```
DELETE FROM table_name 
WHERE ctid IN (
SELECT ctid 
FROM table_name
WHERE table_name.env = 'AE'
LIMIT 1000)
```

Which works, but is incredibly slow (200-250 ms per row deleted) and times out if I go over 1000 a lot.

To find the bottleneck in the query, I ran the query above with `explain (analyze,buffers,timing)` on a smaller version of this query (with LIMIT 1 instead of LIMIT 1000), resulting in the following explain:

```
QUERY PLAN
Delete on dynamic_data  (cost=0.38..4410.47 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=338.913..338.913 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=7972 read=988 dirtied=975
  I/O Timings: read=312.160
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.38..4410.47 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=3.919..13.700 rows=1 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (dynamic_data.ctid = "ANY_subquery".ctid)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 35938
        Buffers: shared hit=4013
        ->  Unique  (cost=0.38..0.39 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=2.786..2.788 rows=1 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=479
              ->  Sort  (cost=0.38..0.39 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=2.786..2.787 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: "ANY_subquery".ctid
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=479
                    ->  Subquery Scan on "ANY_subquery"  (cost=0.00..0.37 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=2.753..2.753 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=474
                          ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.36 rows=1 width=6) (actual time=2.735..2.735 rows=1 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=474
                                ->  Seq Scan on dynamic_data dynamic_data_1  (cost=0.00..4020.71 rows=11093 width=6) (actual time=2.735..2.735 rows=1 loops=1)
                                      Filter: (env = 'AE'::text)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 5614
                                      Buffers: shared hit=474
        ->  Seq Scan on dynamic_data  (cost=0.00..3923.37 rows=38937 width=6) (actual time=0.005..8.130 rows=35939 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=3534
Planning time: 0.354 ms
Execution time: 338.969 ms
```

My main take-away from the query plan is that I/O timings take 312/338 = 92% of the time:

```
actual time=338.913..338.913 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=7972 read=988 dirtied=975
  I/O Timings: read=312.160
```

I can't find anything on how to improve the I/O performance of this query without changing the database configuration. Is this simply an unfortunate effect of the large table rows / database? Or am I missing something important? How do I speed up this delete operation?

Without any resolution I'm defaulting to having a script delete 1 row at a time with separate queries. Far from ideal, so I hope you have suggestions.

*Note that I am not administering the database and not authorized to make any changes to its configuration, nor is it likely that the DBA will change the config to cope with my ill-designed setup.*

Comment: The query only takes 300ms (less than half a second). What kind of timeout did you configure that it "times out"?

Comment: "*rerporting that the logs file are full*" - please share the **exact** error message for that. A delete query does not "fill up the log file".

Comment: Delete statements reads and writes a lot of pages for a single row. How many indexes do you have on this table ? is the table frequently vacuumed ?

Comment: - Time-out -> query concludes without a reponse/error with no effect.
- I will have to reproduce and and will post it as soon as I have the exact error.
- Not frequently vacuumed, and no indices. Would any of those help? Also, what do you mean with 'pages'?

Comment: I mean buffer statistics in the execution plan are related to pages/blocks used by the table and its indexes on disk. Vacuum should help. If there are no indexes it's better because it means less I/O for DELETE statements: so no need to create them.

Comment: @pifor wouldn't it be a fast delete, but slower to find the record?

Comment: If doing this quickly fills up the log files space, then doing it slowly seems to be the solution, rather than the problem.

Comment: If you don't get a response saying it timed out, what makes you think it timed out?

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?